# Check for Null Value and use another instead without querying item twice NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda

I'm selecting two columns form a table via nhibernate.

```
...
.Select(x => new dynamic[]{x.Value1, x.Value2})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

`Value2` can be null so if thats the case it should use `Value3` instead.

Is there a way to solve this issue without querying the object, check if its null and then query it again if thats the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using ternary operator in the select lambda

```
...
Select(x => new dynamic[]{x.Value1, x.Value2 == null ? x.Value3 : x.Value2 })
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I feel a bit silly now, thank you anyway. Even if this would be shorter. `x.Value2 ?? x.Value3`